# How does $\int (u*v)dx = \int u dx \int v dx $ follow from $ (u*v)*w = u*(v*w) $ by taking $w = 1$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution

In Hormander's first book on PDEs he states on page 17 that

$$
(u*v)*w = u*(v*w)
$$
if all except one of the continuous functions $u,v,w$ $\in C(\mathbb{R})$ have compact support. He then says

> taking $w=1$ we find that
>
> $$ \int (u*v)dx = \int u dx \int v dx \quad \quad (*) $$ when $u$ and $v$ have compact
>   support.

I am already familiar with this identity, my question is how this follows from taking $w = 1$ in the previous statement. If I take $w=1$, for the left hand side I have

$$
((u*v)*1)(x) = \int (u*v)(x-y)dy
$$
Then integrating this I get

$$
\begin{align}
\int ((u*v)*1)(x) dx & = \int \int (u*v)(x-y)dy dx \\
& = \int \bigg( \int (u*v)(x-y) dx \bigg) dy \\
& = \int \bigg( \int (u*v)(x) dx \bigg) dy \\
& =  \bigg( \int (u*v)(x) dx \bigg) \int dy \\
& = \infty.
\end{align}
$$

So I don't see how setting $w = 1$ is going to lead to the expression $(*)$? Is the book incorrect or have I made a mistake?

Comment: Can't we simply use Fubini's Theorem to obtain the equation star?

Comment: @JonasLenz Yes, I am aware of that method of obtaining the identity. I want to know why Hormander says it can be be obtained by taking $w=1$ in the expression $(u*v)*w = u*(v*w)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to integrate again. Each side *looks* like a function of one variable, but this function is actually constant because the integral is translation-invariant. In particular,
$$  (v * w)(x) = \int v(x-y) 1 \, dy = \int v(z) \, dz, $$
so "${}*w$" is just the integral over $\mathbb{R}$.
This applies equally well to $(u * v) * w$, and convolution with any constant does the same by linearity, so for any $y$,
$$ \int u * v \, dx = ((u * v) * 1)(y) \\
= (u * (v * 1))(y) = \left(u * \int v \, dx \right)(y) = (u * 1)(y) \int v \, dx = \int u \, dx \int v \, dx $$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
(u*v)*1 &= \int (u*v)(x) \, dx\\
&= \int \int u(y)v(x-y) \, dy \, dx\\
&= \int u(y) \int v(x-y) \, dx \, dy \quad \text{[Fubini]}\\
&= \int u(y) \int v(x) \, dx \, dy \quad \text{[Change of variables $\;x-y  \mapsto x$]}\\
&= \int u(y) \, dy \int v(x) \, dx
\end{align}